# Send Value From jQuery Autocomplete To HiddenField

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-autocomplete, hidden-field

I'm trying to Send the Current Value of AutoComplete jQuery to a HiddenField on ASP

Hidden Field:

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" />
```

When the Page Loads I only assign the HiddenField Value to some TextBox:

```
Protected Sub PrepareSession(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Dim hid = hidden.Value
Requester_NumEmpleado_TB.Text = hid
```

The is the jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("document").ready(function() {
         $("#Requester_NumEmpleado_TB").autocomplete({
             source: 'Search_VB.ashx',
             autoFocus: true,
             select: function(event, ui) {

             }
         });
         $("#<%=hidden.ClientID %>").val("20020177") //this works but i want to send the Autocomplete Value, not the "20020177"
     });
</script>
```

This works for a hardcoded value, but I want to send the value from the Autocomplete, not the "20020177".  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is retrieve the value in the autocomplete field in the `select` callback, and assign it to the value of the hidden field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#Requester_NumEmpleado_TB").autocomplete({
        source: 'Search_VB.ashx',
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var autocomplete_value = $("#Requester_NumEmpleado_TB").val();
            $("#<%=hidden.ClientID %>").val(autocomplete_value);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!, but this only give me an `{Object} Object` as Result

Comment: @J.Chavez I updated my answer.  I had somehow missed typing in the `.val()` portion to retrieve the Text value on the line with `autocomplete_value = $("#Requester_NumEmpleado_TB")` line.  It now uses the `.val()` method call to get the value, instead of the object.